# Is it possible to add pass command line arguments to MSTest when running a test list from VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have a test list in VS2010 that I'm running and I want to pass additional command line arguments when running those tests as if I were calling MSTest.exe from the command line myself. I've googled and searched this forum and haven't found any answers.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure some settings in **testname.testrunconfig** file.

You can also create lists and choose which tests you want to run in **testname.vsdmi** file.

In this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182480%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you can see some information as starting point.

Comment: I'm using VS2010, so your link helped me get to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx) MSDN article.